# How to test an unmounted React component's method that relies on setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have implemented a component (for a typing training app) which tracks key presses on global scope like this:

```
class TrainerApp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        // ...
        this.handlePress = this.handlePress.bind(this);
    }
    handlePress(event) {
        const pressedKey = event.key;
        const task = this.state.task;
        const expectedKey = task.line[task.position];

        const pressedCorrectly = pressedKey == expectedKey;
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const newPosition = prevState.task.position +
                (pressedCorrectly ? 1 : 0);
            return {
                // ...prevState, not needed: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged
                task: {
                    ...prevState.task,
                    position: newPosition,
                    mistakeAtCurrentPosition: !pressedCorrectly
                }
            }
        })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener(this.keyEventTypeToHandle,this.handlePress);
    }
    componentWillUnmount () {
        document.removeEventListener(this.keyEventTypeToHandle,this.handlePress);
    }
    ...
}
```

and I'd like to write some unit-tests using Jest. My initial idea was:

```
describe('TrainerApp.handlePress should',() => {
    test('move to the next char on correct press',() => {

        const app = new TrainerApp();
        app.state.task.line = 'abc';
        app.state.task.position = 0;
        const fakeEvent = { key: 'a' };

        app.handlePress(fakeEvent);

        expect(app.state.task.position).toBe(1);
    });
    ...
});
```

but the problem is `app.handlePress` relies on usage of `this.setState` which is not defined when the component is not mounted yet. Of'course I can modify the `app` like this:

```
test('move to the next char on correct press',() => {

    const app = new TrainerApp();
    app.setState = jest.fn(function(handler) {
        this.state = handler(this.state);
    });
    app.state.task.line = 'abc';
    app.state.task.position = 0;
    const fakeEvent = { key: 'a' };

    app.handlePress(fakeEvent);

    expect(app.state.task.position).toBe(1);
});
```

or even like this:

```
class ExplorableTrainerApp extends TrainerApp {
    setState(handler) {
        this.state = handler(this.state);
    }
}
test('move to the next char on correct press',() => {

    const app = new ExplorableTrainerApp();
    app.state.task.line = 'abc';
    app.state.task.position = 0;
    const fakeEvent = { key: 'a' };

    app.handlePress(fakeEvent);

    expect(app.state.task.position).toBe(1);
});
```

but this seems a very fragile approach (here I rely on the fact that `.setState` is called with the function argument while it can be called with just `newState` argument and hence I'm testing implementation details, instead of just the behaviour. Is there a more robust way to test this?

Comment: You'll need to actually mount your components to access the methods. 'Enzyme' from airbnb works nicely with React for this https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jest.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a few frameworks for testing React components, [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/) and [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library) are both popular and well supported.

Comment: So basically we need to use tools to mount the component to get `setState` to work; and react does not provide a handy methods to mount them only for testing so it's better to use testing frameworks, right?

Comment: You _could_ just mount the component in the DOM: `const app = ReactDOM.render(<TrainerApp />, document.querySelector('.main');`, but the testing frameworks provide methods that allow you to conveniently do things like find components deeper in the tree.